# Select Class(variable) instead of Select New Class{variable = x} in Linq

Tags: c#, linq

This linq works fine:

```
        return (from page in db.WebPages
                where pageids.Contains(page.page_id)
                select new Result
                {
                   a = page.a,
                   b = page.b
                });
```

However I would like to do something like this which does not work:

```
    return (from page in db.WebPages select GetResult(page));


    public Result GetResult(WebPage page)
    {
        return new Result
                {
                   a = page.a,
                   b = page.b
                };

    }
```

This gives an error of no supported translation to Linq.

The reason that I want to do this is because the Result is more complex and the code is done a lot of times so to avoid writing the same thing in every linq select new {} clause.

Comment: Which Linq provider are you using? It's clearly not linq-to-objects. Linq-to-sql, entity framework...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like the following:

```
private static IQueryable<Result> toResults(IQueryable<WebPage> query)
{
  return query.Select(item => new Result
  {
  //...
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
return toResults(db.WebPages);
```

Organizing them like this has worked for me with other query providers, although I haven't worked with Linq-to-SQL personally.

Comment: Can you please give an example of how to use this function. I dont fully understand

Comment: Updated post with a simple usage.  You could have it as instanced or static, depending on where you want to put it.  You could also make an extension method out of it if you wanted to (not sure how widely used you would want it to be).

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to execute the method `GetResult()` in the scope of the database. Linq to Sql / Entities is translated into SQL queries where your method will not work. You will have to go with approach A. Alternatively you can force execution of the later part of your query as Linq to Objects using `AsEnumerable()`:

```
return (from page in db.WebPages
        where pageids.Contains(page.page_id)).AsEnumerable()
       .Select(GetResult);
```

Comment: Yes but in approach A there are about 20 lines in the select new clause and the whole linq statement is repeated so many times. So when I want to change something in the select new clause I have to do it every single time which doesnt sound logic. There must be a way to pass a function to the select which returns the appropriate object.

Comment: @MarwanRoushdy: Added an alternative using `AsEnumerable()` - this has the disadvantage that you are materializing all column values though, be aware of that.

Comment: I cannot use linq to object as I need it to sql. The code inside the function does translate to sql because it had worked in option A

Comment: Did you even try this? Only the `GetResult` part is executed as Linq to objects, the rest remains Linq to Sql

Comment: When you call AsEnumerable the whole list of webpages is executed to the db however this is not possible because there are more sql that is going to be added in other functions so I need it to remain as an Iqueryble

Answer (score 1):

Try this?

`return db.WebPages.Where( x=> x.Contains(page.page_id).Select(x  => GetResult(x));`

Comment: same problem Method 'TagThis.Models.Result GetResult(TagThis.Models.WebPage)' has no supported translation to SQL.